# Highlight specific Word.Range in Outlook.mailItem

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, outlook, vsto, outlook-2010

```
Outlook.Inspector = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
Word.Document document = (Word.Document)inspector.WordEditor;

//I have some code that determines start and end of the range i want to highlight.
//lets say they are:
object start = 0;
object end = 5;

Word.Range rng = document.Range(ref start, ref end);

//I have tried this but it didn't work but it throws an exception that Highlight 
//section is disabled or something like that.
rng.HighlightColorIndex  = WdColorIndex.wdYellow;
```

I also tried to get text from the range and use Word.Find object and to use Find.HitHighlight method on this text but the problem is that it's highlights this text appearances that are out of the specified range.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: would like to know this too

Comment: I could not reproduce this error. For me it worked. Used Outlook 2016. Maybe the problem has to do with the content of the range?